# What Hebrew date requires the most space to spell out in a Ketubah?

Tags: marriage, calendar, riddle

What Hebrew date requires the most space to spell out in a Ketubah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> שלושים יום לחודש אדר הראשון שהוא ראש
>   חודש לאדר השני
>
> "The thirtieth day of Adar the First;
>   which is the beginning of Adar the
>   Second."

For dates like that, hopefully you're using a computer auto-typeset Ketubah that can rearrange the lettering accordingly. If you're trying to squeeze all of that into the small blank provided in a pre-printed Ketubah, print very, very small!

Comment: It might be easier to create your own one from scratch - calligraphy and all!